# Is here a way to undelete very deleted file?

Tags: data-recovery

1. PC not support more OSes than 2 (it includes also live-boot ) - I have windows ( I don't use ) and ubuntu 20.04
2. Programs which I tried ( and didn't worked ) : `grep`, `extundelete`, `debugfs`, `ext4magic`, `foremost`, `lsdel`
3. `testdisk` doesn't show 'undelete' option under disk which I want to recover
4. `scalpel` recovered many files but not this which I wanted to recover... (pdfs, pngs, txt, etc...)
5. filename and directory - `/home/hn/Documents/Gdevelop/My projects/game.json`
6. delete command: `rm -rf /home/hn/Documents/Gdevelop`
7. I'm sure that I'll use CLI so i posted it here.
8. now I'm trying to find it on `/proc` but I'm sure that it's not here because I deleted it few reboots ago... (and few commands ago...)
9. maybe is a directory where is ''changelog'' of all system ? (i know it could be a very giant file but maybe...)

Comment: Try R-Studio Undelete

Comment: r-studio is paid.... i don't waste money on software...

Comment: "Waste" money? No backup? Just recreate the file from scratch then. The only time I ever had to do this, my second version was way better than the first. But then, I learn from my mistakes.

Comment: lol i had about 8000 lines of code. reproduce? good joke :D

Comment: A json-file containing code?

Comment: yup - my code...

Comment: Is this a question? it appears to me like several disconnected sentences.

Comment: yep, idk how to recover files if ^ I have crashes about I said at the topic of thread (-_-)

Comment: Sorry did I say sentences. Please write less, and write clearer. I can't understand what you are saying. It fills by head with ideas, but I don't know what. Is your question "How do I recover a deleted file?"

Comment: i didn't recovered that file yet...

Comment: Is it a "very deleted file", implying you want to recover only one particular, but possibly already overwritten, file, or do you mean "every deleted" file - if the latter, what time range are we speaking of?

Comment: very deleted (pc after reboots and many commands) but i recovered so...

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to recover the files from a backup.

If anything has been writing to the filesystem containing /home/hn/Documents, the file contents (or parts of it) may have been overwritten.

If you remember or have pieces of that code, you can start searching that filesystem with grep.  This may allow you to recover large pieces of code.

```
grep -a -b -C 80 ST_Distance_Sphere  /dev/sda10
```

Better save the output somewhere else.  Don't hold your breath.

Comment: i don't have a backup ?

Comment: Why waste our time with a file that is not important?

Comment: for me it's important -_* i only forgot...

Comment: See edited answer.  You never know.

Comment: i know but grep showed *nothing*

Comment: and i tried many commands...

Comment: btw partition is sda9 not sda10

Comment: Perhaps you searched for ST_Distance_Sphere which is part of my code, not yours?

Comment: no it was before i said about that here and i've tried abot 10 commands with grep (with no result...) empty terminal... (recovery - same...)

Comment: That would mean the blocks of that file were overwritten.  "rm" doesn't do that.  You're sure about the filesystem (I gave only an example!) ?  I tested it with success.

Comment: okay - it give me something like '' redfsfdvghyhnjhmjhnefreigb'' so... and it's too long that terminal ends and i can't copy everything...

Comment: And can you show the command that returned that output?  Literally please.

Comment: every time it changes so... it was only a 'something' to know what i can copy from code...

Comment: idk maybe a virus?

Comment: I'm sorry I tried to help you.  Are you a troll?

Comment: no it's real problem for me....

Comment: I wish you a good night.

Comment: and ok - here is screen record from a second ago - this time nothing ... : link : *https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qq5jlZl5YhllvRH3-zn3PVdMurn7RoHN/view?usp=sharing*

Comment: Unable to process this video.  Si non è vero, è ben trovato!